# Скрипт по созданию превью изображения

Tags: php

Приветствую, есть код:

```
<?php
if ( is_page('/nab/2811/') ) :
?>
<div id="set-new">
        <div class="morepics">{section name=j loop=$nab.adim}<a title="{$nab.name}" href="{$nab.adim[j].link_raw}" target="_blank" rel="mainpic"><img src="/makeup/pic-55.png" /></a>{/section}</div>
</div>
<?php else : ?>
        <p class="glass">Ещё фото {section name=j loop=$nab.adim}<a title="{$nab.name}" href="{$nab.adim[j].link_raw}" target="_blank" rel="mainpic">{$smarty.section.j.index+1}</a>{if not $smarty.section.j.last} | {/if}{/section}</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

это тестовая страница сайта.. нужно создать вместо "pic-55.png" кешировалось и генерировалось изображение определенного размера, а изображение само бралось из 2-й части кода

Comment: Ваш вопрос похож на беспорядочный набор слов! Учитесь логично выражать свои мысли.

Сформулируйте вашу проблему/вопрос четко.

Answer (score 1):

Надо, чтобы сначала работала логика, создавая превьюшку и сохраняя название картинки в переменную, а потом уже шло представление и выводилась картинка. Сформулируйте вопрос, тогда и я уточню ответ.